# Is it possible to install Office 2019 on Windows 10 without uninstalling previous versions?

Tags: windows-10, installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2019

Upon trying to install Office 2019 (x64 version) on Windows10 x64, it displays a message:

"System restart required.. Error Code: 30182-39 (2)"

and links to a page suggesting to restart (which I tried) and then uninstall and reinstall Office. Office 2016 is already installed (also x64 version).

It is a huge hassle to uninstall Office, especially with licensing issues. Is there a way to install 2019 without having to uninstall 2016?

---

Edit: 10/26:
Thanks for the responses! To clarify, here is what is happening:

Right now, my computer only has Office 2016 Pro Plus x64 installed on it from a .iso and activation key from Microsoft.

I am trying to install Office 2019 x64, also with .iso from MS, however without uninstalling Office 2016.

Events:

1) a while ago I downloaded the "Office 2016 Pro Plus x64" .iso from Microsoft and activated it with an "alphanumeric key" from them. I don't recall for this PC specifically, but when I did the same for another PC I have, and tried activating it with an alphanumeric key, it required me to login with the same account that I had acquired the key under (you presumably have only a certain number of activates per key) to complete the activation.

2) I am not sure of whether the Office 2016 was click-to-run or MSI (it was a .iso), but I occasionally see something like "Click to run" with the Office logo next to it in the Task Manager (I presume it is updating components).

3) Given the limited number of activates per key, and no clear way to deactivate, I am concerned that if I were to uninstall Office 2016, I will have completely lost use of that single activation quota (which means if they let you install on 3 PC's and I have it installed on 3 right now, and I uninstall it on this one I'm asking about, I will not be able to reuse this key on this PC or another).

My concern about 3) is that let's say I uninstall 2016, and afterwards, I see that 2019 still can't install; however I need an MS Office installation on my PC, so then I try to re-install 2016 and then either of the following occurs:

a. 2016 installation may now give an error (resulting in there not being any Office available to me on my PC)

or b. I can no longer activate Office 2016 with the key above, as it wasn't previously deactivated and MS thinks it is already installed on the quota of PC's it had assigned to me.

---

Edit 10/28:

I have other Office 2016 Products (MS Project 2016 x64 for example) that aren't covered by Office365, therefore requiring a key (which has a usage quota). I'd like to install Office365 (based on feedback here) and either keep or upgrade these installations to 2019.

Perhaps I should post this as a separate question, however is there a confirmed way to deactivate these other installations (Project) such that MS knows that I can reinstall without quota issues? I saw an article that the best way is to uninstall and then use phone-activation when running into an issue if re-installation is required - however I foresee problems with that method.

Comment: Is your installation of Office 2016 MSI-based or Click-to-Run?

Comment: I have in the past had Office 2010 and Office 2016 installed.  However, in order to do that, one must not be a Click-to-Run installation.  As for the licensing issues you speak of, an Office 2016 license cannot be used to activate Office 2019, so it's not clear what issues you are running into.

Comment: Hi! I have from MS both .iso and activation key for 2016 and 2019, however the error requires me to uninstall 2016, and without clear deactivation I may lose the ability to use its installation key if let's say 2019 still doesn't install and I need to then go back and install 2016. More clarification in the "edited" section of the question that I had just updated.

Comment: Unless you have a VLK installation, you have a Click-to-run installation.  Since your running Office 2016, all versions of Office 2013, have click-to-run for individual licensed installations.  It’s not possible to have a non-Click-to-run without a VLK install.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check which Installation technologies used for the current Office 2016. Because Office 2019 cannot be installed on the same computer with volume licensed MSI version of Office 2016. The following article may be helpful for your issue:
[Supported scenarios for installing different versions of Office, Project, and Visio on the same computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer)

The major version of Office 2019 is staying at 16.0 which is the same version with Office 365 and Office 2016. Therefore, please make sure your are using the same Installation technologies for Office 2019 and Office 2016.

To check the installation technologies for Office 2016, open Word 2016, click **File** > **Account**, under **Product Information**, check if there is an "**Update Options**" button. If there is, it is click-to-run version. If no button, it is MSI version.

Comment: “the same Installation technologies for Office 2019 and Office 2019.” - Please clarify this statement

Answer (score 0):

See the Microsoft article
[Office installed with Click-to-Run and Windows Installer on same computer isn't supported](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-installed-with-click-to-run-and-windows-installer-on-same-computer-isn-t-supported-30775ef4-fa77-4f47-98fb-c5826a6926cd).

You will need to uninstall both Office 2010 and Office 2016, and buy an Office365
license.

I suggest that if Office 2016 is sufficient, to wait with the move to Office365
until there is an important motivation for it.

Comment: Hi! They are both installed from .iso's from Microsoft. I edited the question, however I don't receive the error in your link. As far as I know, the "Click to Run" occasionally appears in my Task Manager when it is presumably updating Office.

Comment: "Click to Run" is also the name for the updater for the MSI version. It might be a common updater for both versions.

Comment: Got the 30 day license for 365, installer gives same error. My largest concern is that I uninstall 2016 (I don't have 2010/13) and then it still gives the error for 365 or any other version I try to install, leaving my PC without the ability to have Office (I am definitely not going to reinstall Windows and rebuild my PC, it's not worth it). There is in fact a feature of 2019/365 that I would like to have (not on 2016) which is why I posted.

Comment: We don't yet know how one of the versions destroys the parameters of the other, which is why it is recommended to uninstall the MSI version *before* installing 365. There is a Microsoft tool in [Uninstall Office from a PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), but I can't say how effective it will be in your situation. I can advise but not guarantee the side-effects.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question ... stating that I had MS Project (not included in Office365) installed as well - does this also need to be uninstalled?

Comment: Apparently so, see [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Is-MS-Project-2016-compatible-with-Office-365/td-p/146282). What feature in Word 2019 is so important as to warrant these expenses?

Comment: From what I've read, all my office2016 installations on this PC are indeed "Click to run", and the office365 that I am trying to install from MS's website is labeled as a .img file. Is there a way to know whether this is click to run or msi?